# Error ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, linux, installation, rvm

I have messed up the Ruby installation on my Ubuntu. I had it installed previously with RVM but I had to uninstall it (`rvm implode`). Now, I have downloaded the latest source (v 2.3.0) and built it from source

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then, I try to install RubyGems but when I try to run `ruby` in terminal I get

> /home/ali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

Why is it still looking for it in *.rvm*?

Comment: Do you still have the `rvm` reference in your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

Comment: Removed and reloaded `.bashrc`. Thanks